# How do you tell a react-select <Select> which options are selected initially on page load?

Tags: react-select

Seems like this should be a pretty common scenario, yet I didn't see any obvious explanation on react-select.com

```
        <Select
            options={options}
            isMulti
            onChange={(e) => changeHandler(e, props.serviceOrderId)}
        />
```

I was hoping there would be a way to pass an array of values that should be selected?

I'm looking through the site and it's all greek to me, if someone could dumb it down for me that'd be great.

Comment: You can use `defaultValue` prop as in here [multi-select](https://codesandbox.io/s/codesandboxer-example-forked-92sy7?file=/example.js)

or you can use `value` prop and pass an array of values to it and when the `onChange ` occurs then you update the value.